# Why can't I access my page and query params after htaccess rules rewrite the url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

1. I have a url of the form --> https://websitename.com/content?id=xyz
2. I want to rewrite the url in the form -->  https://websitename.com/content/xyz
3. I want to be able to access the query param (id) and its value (xyz) on the content page after the url has been rewritten
4. All pages are *.php pages
5. I've used the following htaccess rewrite rule

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   # Hide .php file extension in the urls
   RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php

   RewriteRule ^content/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ content?id=$1 [NC,L]
   ```
6. When I navigate to the rewritten url, it doesn't work and I get the following error:
   "Not Found
   The requested URL was not found on this server"
7. I also can't access the query parameter and its value on the rewritten url
8. But, when I enter the original url, that works and I can access the query parameter and its value

I'd appreciate it a ton if someone can help me find out what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this.

Thanks,
Dexxterr.

Comment: Thanks for adding well formed details kudos. One question here: `https://websitename.com/content?id=xyz` is this url you are hitting on browser? Which should be changed to `https://websitename.com/content/xyz` in browser? Please confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: 
1. I have another page called home where there's a link pointing to  --> https://websitename.com/content/xyz
2. When the above link is clicked it is supposed to take me to that url, which it does but then I get the "not Found" error 
3. If I point the link to --> https://websitename.com/content?id=xyz  , and click it, then it works but is not rewritten and the original url displays in the browser

Comment: RewriteRule ^content/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ content.php?id=$1 [NC,L] may be because your missing .php as shown above. im not sure about this but whenever i write .htaccess file i always write code like RewriteRule ^product-listing/([0-9a-zA-Z=_-]+)/$ product-listing.php?key=$1 [NC,L] this

Comment: @RichPhp: 
1. Thanks for the suggestion. I made the change you suggested and it worked, but my css got all messed up and I had to change the reference to the css file in the header. 
2. All my pages are in the root and the css and js are in their respective folders (root/css and root/js). 
3. The css and js in the page was originally referenced as css/mycssfile in the <head>
4. But after the change you suggested, the styling got all messed up and was fixed only after I changed the css reference in the <head> to  ../css/mycssfile

Comment: if whenever you use .htaccess just in common file which is included on top of everything just define url like this define('URL',example.com'); then just in css link tag use like this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=URL?>/assets/style.css"> same for css it will not messed your css and js code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following once. Please clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Hide .php file extension in the urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^content/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ content.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: 1. The messed up links work correctly with the <base href="/"> you suggested
2. The url rewrite works fine with the following htaccess rules and the <base href="/"> change you suggested. 
```
RewriteEngine On

# Hide .php file extension in the urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^content/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ content.php?id=$1 [NC,L] 
```
3. What do the following 2 lines do? Why are they required?
```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: @Dexxterr, they are conditions which will make sure to get applied only when uri's pages are non-existing else it will get applied to existing pages(eg--> css, js other main pages) where we don't want to apply them, let me know if this helps you.